# Typeahead, cascade, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cascade, typeahead

sorry about my English, but I need some help. I'm trying to make a cascade typeahead based on manufacturers and models of cars. here is the code I have (all this code I used from examples I get from webs, I'm a beginner in web programming.

nuevo_coche.php:
...

```
.marcas,.modelos {
    background-color:#fff;
    font:8pt helvetica;
    color:#000;
    width:250px;
            border-color:#696969;
            border-style :solid;
            border-width :1px;
            height:15pt;
        }

.tt-dropdown-menu {
  font:8pt helvetica;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #000;
  background-color: #e0ffff;
        }


        </style>

        <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

$('input.marcas').typeahead({
       name: 'marcas',
       remote : './marcas.php?query=%QUERY'
});

$('input.modelos').typeahead({
    name: 'modelos',
        remote : './modelos.php?query=%QUERY&nombremarca=' + $('input.marcas').val()
});

        })

        function cancelar() {
            location.href="index.php";
        }
...

<tr>
 <td width="15%">Marca</td>
 <td width="43%"><input id="marcas" type="text" name="marcas" size="20" class="marcas" placeholder="Introduce marca"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="15%">Modelo</td>
 <td width="43%"><input id="modelos" type="text" name="modelos" size="20" class="modelos" placeholder="Introduce Modelo"></td>
```

...

marcas.php:

include ("../conectar.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {

```
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];

$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM marcas WHERE nombremarca LIKE '%{$query}%'");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row['nombremarca'];
}

echo json_encode ($array); //Return the JSON Array
```

}

modelos.php

include ("../conectar.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {

```
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
$nombremarca = $_REQUEST['nombremarca'];

$sel_marcas="SELECT * FROM marcas WHERE nombremarca='$nombremarca'";
$rs_marcas=mysql_query($sel_marcas);
$codmarca=mysql_result($rs_marcas,0,"codmarca");

$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM modelos WHERE nombremodelo LIKE '%{$query}%' AND codmarca='$codmarca'");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row['nombremodelo'];
}

echo json_encode ($array); //Return the JSON Array
```

}

If I put in the line `-- remote : './modelos.php?query=%QUERY&nombremarca=Ford' --` (for example), it works fine, but I dont know how to do it. thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of `input.marcas`. I think you want something like:

```
$('input.modelos').typeahead({
    name: 'modelos',
    remote: './modelos.php?query=%QUERY&nombremarca=' + $('input.marcas').val()
});
```

If the parameter is evaluated at the start then $('input.marcas').val() will appear to be fixed so you will have to find a way of making it call a function to get the result.

All the documentation is here so there will be something in there to help you.

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Comment: I've tried this and do not work, maybe I should have put more code:

Comment: I've seen de documentation and not get anything clear, as i said, i'm newbie in this and all i've is from examples that do more or less what i want... :p

Answer (score 0):

Well I've got a solution, maybe is not de best way to do it but it works:

```
    function lanzarmarca() {

        if (document.getElementById("var").value == 0) {
            $('input.marcas').typeahead({
                name: 'marcas',
                remote : './marcas.php?query=%QUERY'
            });
            document.getElementById("marcas").focus();
        }
        if (document.getElementById("var").value == 1) {
            focus();
        }
    }

    function lanzarmodelo() {
        $('input.modelos').typeahead({
            name: 'modelos',
            remote : './modelos.php?query=%QUERY&nombremarca=' + $('input.marcas').val()
        });
        document.getElementById("modelos").focus();
        document.getElementById("var").value=1;

    }

    function focus() {
        if (document.getElementById("var").value == 1) {
            document.getElementById("marcas").value = "";
            document.getElementById("var").value=0;
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }

    function load() {
           with (document.getElementById("marcas")) {
                selectionStart = selectionEnd = value.length;
                focus();
            }
    }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
```

...

```
<tr>
<td width="15%">Marca</td>
<td width="43%"><input id="marcas" type="text" class="cajaGrande" name="marcas" size="20" class="marcas" placeholder="Introduce marca" onkeypress="lanzarmarca()"><input id="var" type="hidden" name="var" value="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="15%">Modelo</td>
<td width="43%"><input id="modelos" type="text" name="modelos" size="20" class="modelos" placeholder="Introduce Modelo" onkeypress="lanzarmodelo()"></td>
```

I've tried to use onfocus instead of onkeypress but the typeahead script breaks, or typeahead.destroy o input.marcas.val() reset with ""... but nothing of this works fine.

Hope it help or someone find a better way to do this.

Thank's a lot for your help David, it really help me.